# Interrupting a for-loop in bash, but only after an iteration is completed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, for

Is there a way to interrupt/stop a **for**-loop in `bash`, but only *after* the current iteration is completed - ie. "between" **done** and **do**?

I'm running a **for**-loop on several directories, with a command that could be destructive unless it's allowed to complete - so I'd like to stop it when the command is finished with one directory, but before it starts on the next.

(Yes, I know I could've added a `sleep` or a `read` command before **done** - but I *didn't*, and the loop is already running...)

Comment: A C -style `for ((` or sh `for x in a b c`?

Answer (score 2):

For **already running**: assuming the command is a *program* and thus runs as a child *process* under the shell running the script (or part thereof), *and* the script didn't give it a heredoc or herestring for input *or* it has read or at least buffered that input, you can stop **after the *process* finishes** by:

- `kill -STOP` the shell (so it won't do anything *after* the current command)
- wait until the child process finishes and goes zombie
- `kill -KILL` the shell

(All as the same user or `root`, from another shell, of course.) 
If the body of the `do ... done` does two or more things on each iteration, this only catches it after *a* program that takes long enough real time you can get the `-STOP` in, which may or may not be the last program in the iteration.

In some (many?) cases it will work to simply `kill -KILL` the shell up front, which prevents the shell cleaning up its children as normally does, and let the child run and finally get reaped by `init` (or equivalent on your system). However, this *might* result in the child seeing some I/O errors or environment differences or errors or variations with any grandchildren it has, and this might still trigger the 'destructive' results you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the iteration contains and how it's built, you might be able to unlink the executables and then break the script. For example the script looks like this:

```
do_first_thing && \
do_second_thing && \
do_third_thing
```

Assuming you can unlink/move `do_first_thing` globally, that is, when no other script needs it at the moment, you:

- unlink it or rename it, so that the script won't start it
- watch in `ps` the progress of the iteration
- when the loop starts idle repeats, you can kill it.

You can also link the first command in the script to another script containing `sleep` or `read` that will give you time and opportunity to break the loop harmlessly.